# Can I remove the Xamarin version of OpenTK and use another?

Tags: macos, opentk, xamarin.mac

I've down loaded visual studio for mac and have created a cross platform solution. I want to use OpenTK v2 (not the one supplied with xamarin).

The problem is that there appears to be an OpenTK namespace that is used run the Xamarin.Mac even when it isn't referenced. The types (Vector4 etc) and the Math Helper class show up in my solution even if the reference isn't showing in the references section.

When I add the OpenTK v2 .dll to the packages (from nuget) I get errors saying 'The imported type 'Opentk.Vector3' (or whatever the type) is defined multiple times. Once in OpenTk and the other in Xamarin.mac (v0).

I've deleted the reference to Xamarin.Mac and the error goes away, but then of course I get errors saying I can't use CoreGraphics etc.

Is there some way of specifying which type you mean? Or removing the references to OpenTK that shouldn't really be there?

Ive tried OpenTK.Matrix4 mat = new OpenTK.Matrix4() but it still doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Set an `Alias` for the referenced assembly (reference properties):

[image]

2) Add an `extern alias` to the top of your source file(s):

```
extern alias OpenTK2;
```

3) You can then use a `using alias` or the fully qualified name:

```
using AlphaFunction = OpenTK2::OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.AlphaFunction;
~~~

var alpha = AlphaFunction.Always;
alpha = OpenTK2::OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.AlphaFunction.Equal
```

Comment: This works, at least the project compiles without error, but on run it gives TargetInvocationException when a class, which is using OpenTK is loaded.
Is there anything else required?