# Is there a version of Xamarin.Mac without the Opentk namespace

Tags: opentk, xamarin.mac

On Visual Studio mac the Xamarin.Mac 3.0.0.290 (provided by visual studio) has the OpenTK namespace in it which is causing me headaches! Is there a version of Xamarin.Mac that can replace this that doesn't have this namespace? I'm targeting .Net4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explain more clearly what the issues you are having. Every Xamarin.Mac contains the OpenTK namespace, as we use a number of Vector and other types internally.

```
$ monop -r:/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/4.5/Xamarin.Mac.dll | grep OpenTK | wc -l
      21

$ monop -r:/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.Mac/Xamarin.Mac.dll | grep OpenTK | wc -l
      21
```

Comment: So true - the question wasn't well though out but your answer does help. Its related to another question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702057/can-i-remove-the-xamarin-version-of-opentk-and-use-another) where I tried to use opentk from open source so I didn't have to change a lot of code to use some of different enums and code in the (older?) version of xamarin opentk. I've decided to use the built in version, accept I need to make changes and p-invoke some methods that aren't there.